# PKI certificate import

Tags: import, pki

When I login to my bank account using https, it's only a server side SSL authentication before I enter my login info. My browser does the server authentication based on the certificate info from the server during SSL session. I did not have to do any manual import of server certificate as a trusted cert into my browser. It just happens at runtime during SSL exchange.

On the other hand, I have also seen applications where one has to manually import the certificate (using keytool for e.g.) when you look into their install guide.

Question is: If the certificate info is exchanged in the beginning of SSL session, each side has enough info to authenticate the other side. Why would some apps require manual import of certs from each other between client and server. Be it either or both side authentication.

ADDITIONAL INFO based on the responses below:
I was referring the scenario where I was installing a commercial software based on client-server model with client side SSL authentication turned ON. I installed the server on machine A and 2 clients on different machines all in my private network. During install, server generates a self-signed certificate locally. So do the 2 clients. Once installation is complete, I was asked to copy the clients' certs to server machine and manually import them as trusted certs. Also, copy the server cert to client machines and do the import into their trusted store. They provided a wrapper tool on top of java keytool to perform the cert import. **Why** is this manual import necessary here? The client and server will anyway exchange certificate info during SSL handshake and perform the authentication. Again, these are self-signed certs and CA involved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a certificate is signed by a certificate authority so it depends on which certificate authorities your browser trusts. If the Web server sends a certificate signed by a certificate authority that’s trusted by the browser/application and the certificate is valid, you shouldn’t get any warnings whatsoever.

On the other hand, if the browser receives a certificate from the Web server and it doesn’t trust the certificate authority that signed that certificate, the browser will take some action — at the very least, it should warn you about this. When you import a certificate from a Web site, you’re essentially telling your browser that you have decided to trust that certificate independently of who signed it.

**Edit:** The same reasoning applies: The keystore keeps a list of trusted certificate authorities and their corresponding certificates. The whole concept of PKI is to have a hierarchy of *trusted* CAs that emit signed certificates for other parties. If a certificate is self-signed, there’s no valid trust chain — how will Java know that the certificate hasn’t been forged by an attacker?

You’re assuming that a connection between a client and a Web server is implicitly trusted just because certificates are exchanged during the SSL handshake. What if a man in the middle poses as the Web server and, instead of sending the server certificate, sends his own certificate instead? How would clients know that the certificate received by the man in the middle is not to be trusted? If the certificate is signed by a trusted CA, or if the certificate has been manually added to the keystore as a trusted certificate, the client can check whether it should trust the certificate or not.

Comment: Fair enough. But in the scenario I explained, only SSL client authentication is turned ON. What's the need to import server cert into clients? You only need to import client cert into server.

Comment: @tushima In SSL, server certificates are always required and validated. Only client certificates are optional. If server certificates aren’t validated, a man in the middle can impersonate the server.

Answer (score 0):

An SSL server's certificate has to be "vouched for" by a certificate authority (CA). Your browser (or other program) contains a list of CAs it trusts. If you're using a site that is *not* certified by one of the standard CAs, then you'd have to import its CA in order for the verification to succeed.

No legitimate site (especially for online banking) should require you to use an "alternative" CA. Only do this for sites where you're not sending super-sensitive data.